# background image event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

If a HTML element (e.g. `div`) has a CSS background image is it possible to assign an event handler that is triggered when the user clicks on the background image, but not any other part of the element?

If so, a JQuery example would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's probably an easier way to do it, but you could put another div behind with the click event on it.

Comment: Why not just assign the event to the element itself? Is the element bigger than the background image?

Comment: Background image is not part of the DOM. It's possible to write a jQuery function to read the CSS and detect if click event happened on the background or not. But it's not possible directly through DOM API

Comment: Would we be correct in assuming the background image only takes up part of the div?

Comment: yes, background image is smaller than the div

Comment: would we also be correct in assuming that this is a toggle image (e.g. for a drill down)?

Comment: @Joseph you would be incorrect

Comment: @Don give us more info on what you're trying to accomplish from a UI perspective. As most have said, there's likely a much easier way to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

While it's not possible to detect a click on the background image, you can use some clever JS and CSS wizardry and come up with a masking element over the background image like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ahmednuaman/75Rxu/, here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="bg_img_1"></div>
<div id="bg_img_2">
    <div id="hit"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
#bg_img_1
{
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/100/100');   
}
#bg_img_2
{
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/100/100');   
}
#hit
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #000000;
    opacity: .3;
    margin: 50px;
}
```

JS:

```
function handleClick(e)
{
    console.log(e.target.id);
}

$( '#bg_img_1' ).click( handleClick );
$( '#hit' ).click( handleClick );
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a better and simple way to achieve this here is my solution

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("*").click(function(event)
{
    if(event.target.nodeName == 'BODY')
    {
        alert('you have just clicked the body background');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic code that only work in `x` axis to show it's possible with injection of an `img` element with background-image url value as it's `src` and detecting the background image height and width to calculate if click happened on background image or not.

This code needs tons of improvement. It doesn't work in `y` axis. Also `background-position` and `background-size` are not involved. But it's easy to add those futures.

Here is [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3WtET/5/):

And here is jQuery code:

```
$('#d').bind('click', function(e){
    var d = $(this),
        bg = {};
    //insert an image to detect background-image image size
    $('body').append(
        $('<img/>').attr('src',
                   d.css('background-image').split('(')[1].split(')')[0]
    ).attr('class', 'testImage'));
    bg.h = $('.testImage').height();
    bg.w = $('.testImage').width();
   console.log(bg, e.offsetX, $('.testImage').width());

    if(e.offsetX >  $('.testImage').width()){
        $('#l').text('it was NOT on background-image');
    }
    else{
        $('#l').text('it was on background-image');
    }
   $('.testImage').hide();
})
```

Comment: I started going down this route too. But while you might get it to work, it depends on knowing and dealing with the `background-repeat` and `background-position` values - the latter especially is a huge pain to parse. I can't recommend this direction.

Comment: The whole idea is basically wrong. When you want to have different behavior then just add a DOM element. OP is making stuff for his self!